# ES6 default parameters weird behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

```
const initialState = {
  username: "default"
}

export function currentUser(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.SET_CURRENT_USER:
      console.log(state)
      console.log(initialState)
      debugger
      return _.extend({}, state, action.user)
```

When I print `state` I get an empty object instead of `{username: "default"}`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Maybe you *did* pass an empty object to `currentUser` explicitly? The default value only appears when you pass `undefined`. Please show us the call.

Comment: This looks like a redux app. a `{}` is probably getting passed in.

Answer (score 3):

A quick test in the chrome console using similar code gives the expected results, and not your reported error.

Maybe you actually did call the function with an empty object?